# Imprimir jTextArea en Java en tiempo real

Tags: java

Como lo dice el titulo quisiera que en mi jTextArea imprimiera de tal forma que al ir ejecutando cada paso que tengo en mi programa lo fuera mostrando, ya que me muestra todas las impresiones al final.
Manejo `append("texo")` en todas mis impresiones.

```
Conexion.preparacion = Conexion.conexion.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM TABLA3 "
                + " WHERE CODIGO_TICKET = ALL(SELECT CODIGO FROM TABLA1 WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '" + fechaDesde + "' AND '" + fechaHasta + "')");
        Conexion.preparacion.executeUpdate();

        Vistas.Resp.txtArea.append("SE ELIMINÓ CORRECTAMENTE TABLA TABLA2\n"
                + "--------------------------------------------\n");

        Conexion.preparacion = Conexion.conexion.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM TABLA3 "
                + "WHERE CODIGO = ALL(SELECT CODIGO FROM TABLA2 WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '" + fechaDesde + "' AND '" + fechaHasta + "')");
        Conexion.preparacion.executeUpdate();
        Vistas.Resp.txtArea.append("SE ELIMINÓ CORRECTAMENTE TABLA TABLA3\n"
                + "--------------------------------------------\n");

        Conexion.preparacion = Conexion.conexion.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM TABLA2 "
                + "WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '" + fechaDesde + "' AND '" + fechaHasta + "'");
        Conexion.preparacion.executeUpdate();
        Vistas.Resp.txtArea.append("SE ELIMINÓ CORRECTAMENTE TABLA TABLA1\n"
                + "--------------------------------------------\n");

        Vistas.Resp.txtArea.append("**********REALIZADO**********\n");
```

Todas estas impresiones se muestran pero solo al finalizar, mientras el jTextArea se mantiene vació.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigando lo que @Ruslan López respondió conseguí  lo que buscaba, espero le sirva a alguien.

En mi Frame en el metodo main sustitui esto:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Resp().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

por esto

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Resp().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

y en donde tengo la acción que realiza mi botón agrego lo siguiente y dentro de ello agrego mi método que contiene las impresiones(**SQL.inserts(fDesde, fHasta);**).

```
final SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {

                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        SQL.inserts(fDesde, fHasta);
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                worker.execute();
```

Con todo esto muestra la salida en mi TextArea  conforme se ejecutan los SQLs.

Comment: No olvides por favor marcar como aceptada la respuesta que dio solución a tu pregunta

Comment: @BetaM la flecha hacia arriba es para respuesta útil, si ella lo resolvió con esto debería aceptar su propia respuesta si así lo quiere.

Comment: Pues esa fue la recomendación @RuslanLópez por eso le comenté "la respuesta" para que ella elija cual marcar como aceptada

Comment: Como comentario adicional para Anayeli y esperando que no te desilusione saberlo... para efectos practicos es práctiamente lo mismo `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` que `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, pues solo hay un hilo de gráficos, no es como que awt y swing tuvieran su hilo independiente cada uno. Otro truco además que podrías agregar a tu repertorio es el tipo de retorno Void, es útil para registrar observables de promesas (procesos asíncronos) que no retornan nada pero que quieres saber cuando hayan terminado.(http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Ejemplo_sencillo_con_SwingWorker)

Comment: Lo tomaré en cuenta, Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

no encuentro nada mal con tu codigo, lo que puede estar sucediendo es que todo el codigo se ejecuta tan rapido, que da la impresion de que imprime todo al finalizar, si lo que deseas, es que luego de cada paso, haya una pausa para dar la impresion de que esta ejecutando la tarea, lo que puedes hacer es agregar:

 `Thread.sleep(tiempo en milisegundos);` 
para que haya una pausa en la aparente estar haciendo el proceso, tu codigo quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
Conexion.preparacion = Conexion.conexion.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM TABLA3 "
                + " WHERE CODIGO_TICKET = ALL(SELECT CODIGO FROM TABLA1 WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '" + fechaDesde + "' AND '" + fechaHasta + "')");
        Conexion.preparacion.executeUpdate();

        Vistas.Resp.txtArea.append("SE ELIMINÓ CORRECTAMENTE TABLA TABLA2\n"
                + "--------------------------------------------\n");

    try{
        Thread.sleep(2500);
    }catch(Exception ex){}

        Conexion.preparacion = Conexion.conexion.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM TABLA3 "
                + "WHERE CODIGO = ALL(SELECT CODIGO FROM TABLA2 WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '" + fechaDesde + "' AND '" + fechaHasta + "')");
        Conexion.preparacion.executeUpdate();
        Vistas.Resp.txtArea.append("SE ELIMINÓ CORRECTAMENTE TABLA TABLA3\n"
                + "--------------------------------------------\n");

    try{
        Thread.sleep(2500);
    }catch(Exception ex){}

        Conexion.preparacion = Conexion.conexion.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM TABLA2 "
                + "WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '" + fechaDesde + "' AND '" + fechaHasta + "'");
        Conexion.preparacion.executeUpdate();
        Vistas.Resp.txtArea.append("SE ELIMINÓ CORRECTAMENTE TABLA TABLA1\n"
                + "--------------------------------------------\n");

    try{
        Thread.sleep(2500);
    }catch(Exception ex){}

        Vistas.Resp.txtArea.append("**********REALIZADO**********\n");
```

**NOTA**: los try y catch son porque la operacion Thread.sleep(), lanza InterruptedException.

Comment: Esa es una forma de evidenciar lo que pasa, sin embargo la mejor práctica es usar el hilo de gráficos y agregarle las tareas que tengan que ver con la interfaz para evitar problemas de concurrencia y actualizaciones demoradas como posiblemente pase en este caso. Esto se hace con `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

Comment: Si, lo investigue y logre hacerlo. Muchas Gracias